# MIPS how to do 'less than' without the blt instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

MIPS has an instruction to do `blt` (branch if less than). For example:

```
blt $t0, $t1,target  #branch to target if $t0<=$t1.
```

I want to know how to do this same operation using only Equal or Not Equal:

```
bne $rt, $rs, target #Branch to target if $a0 and $a1 are NOT equal
```

or

```
beq $rt, $rs, target #Branch to target if $a0 and $a1 are equal
```

Comment: I assume that you mean that those are the only two _branch_ instructions that are allowed, while other types of instructions are ok to use. If so, just use `slt` followed by `bne`.